# NextAuth selecting a different google account for login

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

Using NextAuth with google provider, how can i log completely out of the session and ensure that upon signing-in again, i am brought to the account selection page instead of getting logged in straightaway?

Here's my simple NextJs login/logout component:

```
import type { NextPage, NextPageContext } from "next";
import { getSession, signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
    const { data, status } = useSession();

    return (
        <>
            {data?.user ? (
                <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
            ) : (
                <button onClick={() => signIn("google")}>Sign In</button>
            )}
            {data?.user?.name}
        </>
    );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context: NextPageContext) {
    const session = await getSession(context);
    return {
        props: { session }
    };
}

export default Home;
```

Current behaviour: Upon initial login, the app routes to google account selection page, i enter credentials and login. I then logout. Upon logging in again, the app automatically logs in with the previously selected account.

Expected behavior: show google account selection page upon each login attempt.

Answer (score 13):

so the solution is mentioned in the next auth docs with the reason here:https://next-auth.js.org/providers/google

to get the account selection screen each time, add the `authorization` block to your options like so:

```
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code"
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
```